# Convert to Beta Function

Tags: calculus

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$$
Stuck trying to convert this into the Beta Function. Start with $x=\sqrt{\tan t}$, got integral in form  $\sin(2t)$,substituted $sin(2t)=z$ , after couldn't find way. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Letting $x=\dfrac1t$ , we get $~2I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$ , which can be expressed in terms of the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) by setting $u=\dfrac1{1+x^4}$ .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24492/discussion-on-answer-by-lucian-problem-with-converting-to-beta-function).

Comment: @BetterWorld For math rendering in chat, install robjohn's ChatJax Bookmark, instructions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297/83702). To participate in chat, you'd have to register your account, it seems. That's not much work, and would allow you to vote too, so unless you have a specific reason not to register, I would recommend registering. Regardless, the comments under this answer aren't the right place to discuss the other question.